# How to Passing Iterates Data to setOnInfoWindowClickListener

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an iterates data from a JSONArray Object like this:

```
try{
        for (int i = 0; i < arrResponse.length(); ++i){
            JSONObject objResponse = arrResponse.getJSONObject(i);
            Integer idShop = objResponse.getInt("ID");
            String name = objResponse.getString("Name");
            String address = objResponse.getString("Address");
            Double slat = objResponse.getDouble("lat");
            Double slong = objResponse.getDouble("long");
            LatLng shopLocation = new LatLng(slat, slong);}}
```

I use the iterates data (idShop, name, address, etc) to mark the point of interest place on my map with this code below:

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(shopLocation)
                    .title(idShop+" "+name)
                    .snippet(address)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker_shop)));
```

Then i put a click listener into every object that created by marker with this code:

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent(OrderActivity.this, Cart1Activity.class);
                    // intent.putExtra("IDShop", ""+idShop);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

How do I get the "idShop" data when I click on a marker, then passing it to intent? I use this code on setOnInfoWindowClickListener:

```
intent.putExtra("IDShop", ""+idShop);
```

But it doesn't get the real data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code above you can simply get title from marker, split it on space character and take first element in the resulting array. This is your id.

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(marker.getTitle().split(" ")[0]);
```

Not very oriented on objects...

Comment: Thank you MaciejGorski for solving my problem.